# Projection of cocyclic Gaussian primes on the real axis

Tags: nt.number-theory, prime-numbers, symmetry, goldbach-type-problems

I just stumbled upon https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2372062/4-concylic-points-of-gaussian-primes after a quick Google search about cocyclic Gaussian primes.

As I've been investigating about Goldbach related problems for quite a long time, I would like to ask this question:

Suppose we have a set of cocyclic Gaussian primes whose symmetry group contains the dihedral group of order $8$ as a subgroup, and whose center has an argument of $k\pi/4$ with $k\not\equiv 0\pmod 4$.

Does the orthogonal projection of these cocyclic points on the real axis give rise to a prime constellation? If so could it shed a light on Hardy-Littlewood prime $k$-tuple conjecture?

Edit: note that due to the symmetry hypothesis, the thus obtained prime constellation should be symmetric in terms of prime gaps, and consequently the center of the "Gaussian prime circle" should be projected on the half sum of two consecutive primes.